# How do you open html in google chrome?

Tags: html

[I got it working now, it was just a browser error]
My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

So the page should have the title, Test, but no, it just shows my code.So in a new tab it shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

instead. Can I get it to say the title?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Thanks for the computer specs, however more important information would be how you are invoking Chrome to load your HTML page.

Comment: I am just double clicking on the html file. Is this wrong?And, yes, it is html.

Comment: it is strange that the MIME type HTML is not recognized in **your** Google Chrome. Try re-installing it.

Comment: (Joke) Can I see this in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code into textmate
saved the file as test.html
and doubled clicked on it.

It worked perfectly. It seems like a browser issue, have you tried reinstalling them. How about try it on another computer? Is the file name end with .html?

how about

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Hi</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Are you working?</p>
</body>

</html>
```

does that work?

Comment: yeaa quite, try reinstall chrome, installing firefox and/or opera. chrome and safari use the same rendering engine maybe something is goin terrible wrong..?

Answer (score 3):

As a recent Mac OS adopter I too ran into this. For me, it was due to using *TextEdit*, and expecting it to act like Notepad.

When you save a .html file in TextEdit, it encodes the HTML and wraps it for you, without any notification.

Viewing source, or opening the file in vim or more in terminal shows what has been applied:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1265">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 13.0px Helvetica}
    p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 13.0px Helvetica; min-height: 16.0px}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;html&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;head&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;title&gt;Test&lt;/title&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;/head&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;body&gt;</p>
<p class="p2"><br></p>
<p class="p1">&lt;/body&gt;</p>
<p class="p1">&lt;/html&gt;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the real issue.  Any ideas on how to make TextEdit not behave this way?

Comment: Yep - there's two options that change TextEdit's behaviours. The first is when opening/saving an existing HTML file, check the option to view as plain text:

Preferences -> Open and Save -> Display HTML files as HTML code instead of formatted text

For creating new HTML files, use Preferences -> New Document -> Format -> Plain Text

At the end of the day, you may be better off just not using TextEdit for html.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your `<title>` tag.

Sobstitute `<title>Test</title>` with `<title>Test</title>`.

Check that you've saved your html page **.html** extension and you should also do better to add a *doctype* like `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of your *web-page*.

Comment: how do I do that? (Sorry, I just started today)

Comment: Just **edit** your web-page and add the **doctype** at the beginning.

Comment: So like: <!DOCTYPE html>   <html>
<head>
<title>Test<title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Comment: like:  `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body></body></html> `

Answer (score 0):

`<title>Test<title>` - you have not closed the second `title` tag, change it to `</title>`. And just to be sure - *Title* does not have to show up in the page you open. If you want to actually see the title, add it within your `<body>` like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Open the properties of the file (Right click -> properties), then check if the name of the file is 'fileName.html.text', if yes, you need to go to 'Folder Options' -> 'View' -> and unmark 'Hide extensions for known file types,
Now change the name of the file to 'fileName.html'.